# Where to start to integrate two zend applications

Tags: zend-framework, magento, integration

I would like to integrate two web application (share users) both based on Zend Framework. Where would you start?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Identify all the possible URLs in each application
- Write a small routing application
- Have your small routing application identify which URL belongs to each application, and then manually "include" the `index.php` file for each application after manually setting up the environment that the application's `.htaccess` would normally send

(also, Magento uses components of the Zend Framework, but it's not a Zend Framework application)

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is share users, you just need to have each web application map users to one another whenever you do your regular authentication mechanism -- if you log in to WebAppA, then whenever WebAppB checks credentials it should look to see if you're logged into WebAppB, which should be existing functionality, but then if you're not logged into WebAppB, check if you are logged into WebAppA...

If usernames line up, this is easy to medium difficulty depending on the authentication schemes, otherwise just prompt the user once to authenticate to their other account and store the mapping on a successful authentication.